# domain-search value on my clients computer

Tags: bind, ubuntu-12.04, dhcp-server, resolv.conf, dns-server

I need help with configure my DNS and DHCP server - I have spent some time searching on google but have not got any informations regarding my problem.

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server running and use BIND as the DNS server.

In my client Ubuntu 13.10 computer I get my domain in the search value

```
search example.com
```

So when I type in something in the address bar in Firefox then I am redirected to example.com instead of google.com for example.

So what information do I need to change in my DNS or DHCP server so that my clients will get google.com as my default search (domain-search) value in resolv.conf ?

Comment: Um, that's not what that option is for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** what **search** in `resolv.conf` does.

It specified the DNS **servers** that your PC will use for DNS lookups, and the **search domain** used for hostname-only lookups.

Example:

```
nameserver 192.168.50.11
nameserver 192.168.50.12
search mynet.local
```

In the above snippet, the servers `192.168.50.11` and `192.168.50.12` will be used for lookups, with the `mynet.local` domain being appended to requests with no domain (e.g. `nslookup myhost`).

For a typical network using DNS and DHCP, these values will be contained within your DHCP configuration, and `resolv.conf` will be populated automatically by your network configuration once your machine obtains a DHCP lease.

To actually do what you want (make Google the default search engine in Firefox), check out [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968367) (though YMMV).

Comment: Thanks for more details about what the search does in resolv.conf

Only thing I noticed was after I added my own DNS then the address bar in Firefox stopped redirecting me to the google.com if domain or anything I typed in could not be found.
If I change the resolv.conf to google.com then it starts to behave normally again ... so thats why I thought maybe I needed to change that.